# Prove that if $X$ is of class $L^p$, it is of class $L^q$, for $(0\lt q\lt p)$.

Tags: probability-theory, vector-spaces

I can prove that if $X$ is of class $L^2$, it is of class $L^1$, since $E^2(|X|)\le E(|X|^2)\lt\infty$.
How to prove that in general if $X$ is of class $L^p$, it is of class $L^q$, for $(0\lt q\lt p)$. The hint given is to consider the event $A=(|X|\le1)$ and $B=(|X|\gt1)$.

Comment: You should try following the hint? Write $E[|X|^q] = E[|X|^q \mid |X| \leq 1] + E[|X|^q \mid |X| > 1]$ and bound the terms separately.

Comment: If the measure of $X$ is finite, a hypothesis that is needed, then $\int_X|f|^q=\int_A|f|^q+\int_B|f|^q\leq 1\cdot\mu(A)+\int_B|f|^p\leq \mu(A)+\int_X|f|^p$. An example that shows that the claim, as written, is not true could be $f(x)=1/x$ on $X=[1,+\infty)$, $p=2$ and $q=1$.

Comment: @logarithm what is $\mu (A)$ stands for?

Comment: The measure of $A$, its probability which is likely your case.

Comment: @RhysSteele So can I say "since $E[|X|^p]\lt\infty$, $E[|X|^p||X|\gt1]\lt\infty$. Thus, $E[|X|^q||X|\gt1]\lt\infty$"?

Comment: It is true that for $p>q$, $E[|X|^p \mid |X|>1] < \infty$ implies that $E[|X|^q \mid |X|>1] < \infty$ since if $|X| > 1$ then $|X|^p > |X|^q$. Since my comment this has been explained well in the answer by Foobaz John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments
$$
E|X|^q=E|X|^q I(|X|\leq 1)+E|X|^q I(|X|> 1)\tag{0}
$$
Obviously 
$$
E|X|^q I(|X|\leq 1)\leq 1\tag{1}
$$
while
$$
|X|^q I(|X|> 1)\leq |X|^p I(|X|> 1)
$$
since $p>q>0$ whence 
$$
E|X|^q I(|X|> 1)\leq E|X|^p I(|X|> 1)\leq E|X|^p<\infty\tag{2}
$$
By (1) and (2) it follows from (0) that $E|X|^q$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, by Jenson’s Inequality:

$$E[X^q]^{p/q}\leq E[X^p].$$